# Mouse pointer disappears when clicked inside the grid and reappears when moved out of the grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application, where in the mainwindow.xaml - I have a grid and some buttons around it. Grid looks as below

```
<Window 
        xmlns:modgn="clr-namespace:BentleyG0505.MobileDgn.Net.Controls;assembly=MobileDgnNet"/>

<Grid>
            <modgn:WpfViewportHost x:Name="TheDgnViewport" ViewIndex="0" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                           MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" >
                <modgn:WpfViewportHost.Background>            
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding IsMapDark, Converter={StaticResource WhiteOrBlack}}"/>
                </modgn:WpfViewportHost.Background>
            </modgn:WpfViewportHost>
    </Grid>
```

And I have buttons like [Open], [New], [Save]. The grid inturn have the map and it can be loaded by using [Open].

> Mouse tap/click on the map (grid), disappears the mouse cursor and it reappears when i move the mouse over the buttons or move out of the application.

I dont have any mouse override event with the application. So my prediction is the problem could be with WPF. Please help me to figure out what could be the reason

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Hi Everyone - Can I get some response on this post. thanks in advance.